# Можно ли написать программу в VS 2015 под Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-xp

Коллеги здравствуйте!

Мне тут нужно напрогать простую программу для старого компа, на котором стоит 2 ГБ оперативной памяти и Windows XP. Ставить на него Visual Studio 2008 как-то время затратно.
**Вопрос такой**:
могу ли я написать программу на VS 2015 (сборка x86 разумеется) на компе, где установлен Windows 7, а потом перенести написанный софт на старый комп в Win XP (чтобы всё заработало, разумеется)? Какие-нибудь есть подводные камни?

Comment: Да. Настроить что-то в свойствах проекта надо только.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35666906/8674428

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  Из подводных камней могут встретиться проблемы с использованием функций ядра ОС, отсутствующих у хр, но это как правило довольно специфичные функции.